# Error in ratio of two numbers

Tags: error-function

How tow find error associated with a ratio $R$, when both the numerator and denominator contains error. For example

$$ R=\frac{(A \pm \Delta A)}{(B\pm\Delta B)}.$$

Answer (score 2):

Assume that $\displaystyle \left|\frac{\Delta B}{B}\right|<1$, then you may write
$$
R=\frac{(A \pm \Delta A)}{(B\pm\Delta B)}=\frac{(A \pm \Delta A)}{B}\times \frac{1}{1\pm\frac{\Delta B}{B}}=\frac{(A \pm \Delta A)}{B}\times \left( 1\mp\frac{\Delta B}{B}+\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{(\Delta B)^2}{B^2}\right)\right)
$$ giving, **to the first order:**
$$
R=\frac{(A \pm \Delta A)}{(B\pm\Delta B)}\approx \frac{A}{B}\left(1-\frac{\Delta B}{B}\right)
+\frac{\Delta A}{B}.$$

Comment: What if the error is not symmetric (for more general case)? Also I want to write it as $`R\pm \Delta R`$.

Answer (score 2):

I'll assume $\Delta A$ and $\Delta B$ are non-negative.

If $\Delta B = |B|$ then there is no upper bound on $R$.
If $\Delta B > |B|$ then there is neither an upper bound nor lower bound on $R$.
So let's suppose that $0 \leq \Delta B < |B|$.
Then the informal notation,

$$ R=\frac{(A \pm \Delta A)}{(B\pm\Delta B)},$$

interpreted as $R = \frac ab$ where $A - \Delta A \leq a \leq A + \Delta A$
and $B - \Delta B \leq b \leq B + \Delta B$,
implies that

$$
\frac{(A - \Delta A)}{(B + \Delta B)} \leq R \leq \frac{(A + \Delta A)}{(B - \Delta B)}.
$$

Let 
$$ R_0 = \frac{AB + (\Delta A)(\Delta B)}{B^2 - (\Delta B)^2} $$

and let 
$$ \Delta R = \frac{A\Delta B + B \Delta A}{B^2 - (\Delta B)^2}. $$

Then
$$ R_0 - \Delta R \leq R \leq R_0 + \Delta R.$$

Note that $R_0 \geq \frac AB,$ with equality if and only if $\Delta B = 0.$